# How to allow Safari camera and microphone permissions in a TestCafe test

Tags: testing, automation, safari, testcafe, saucelabs

I would like to click 'Allow' on the camera and microphone permission dialogs that show up in my TestCafe test. How can I handle these dialogs in TestCafe to click Allow?

[First Safari camera permission dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZyLg.png)

[Second Safari camera and microphone permission dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjKeP.png)

I've tried the following solution in my test to click the Allow button but it didn't work and the dialog remains:

```
    await t
      .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
      .click(Selector('button').withText('Allow'));
```

Alternatively, is there a way to programmatically configure Safari's camera and microphone permissions to Allow? I am running the automated test on Sauce Labs and would like the camera and microphone permissions to be Allowed so I can use Safari's mock capture devices during the test.

For example, I can enable Safari's mock capture devices programmatically on Sauce Labs by executing the following commands under the `preExec` sauce configuration in `.sauce/config.yml`:

```
  - name: "Safari in sauce"
    platformName: "macOS 12"
    browserName: "safari"
    mode: sauce
    preExec:
      - /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :WebKitMockCaptureDevicesEnabled bool 1' ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
      - /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :WebKitPreferences.mockCaptureDevicesEnabled bool 1' ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
      - /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :WebKitPreferences.mediaCaptureRequiresSecureConnection bool 0' ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
      - /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :WebKitMediaCaptureRequiresSecureConnection bool 0' ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

Is there a way I can do similar configurations for the camera and microphone permissions in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively, is there a way to programmatically configure Safari's camera and microphone permissions to Allow?

The [setNativeDialoagHandler](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402684/reference/test-api/testcontroller/setnativedialoghandler?search#header) method is not intended for handling the `Camera Permission` dialog. Try to execute each instruction from the `preExec` section programmatically using the [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) method before the test run.